# LOAD DATA INFILE with quotes around timestamp that contains microseconds

Tags: mysql, csv, batch-file, load-data-infile

I've got a **Windows batch file** that reads all the CSV files in its directory.  Problem I have is that the lines of the CSV have double quotes in the timestamp, and also include a microsend.  I'm quite sure the below code has to be close, but its either imports a single line and dumps NULL in the timestamp column, or it indicates that that "SET was unexpected at this time" which I think is due to an unescaped character because this is being run as a **Windows batch file**  My code is below and below that is a sample of the CSV file data.

```
echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN ("*.csv") DO (
set old=%%~dpnxf
set new=!old:\=\\!
mysql -e "LOAD DATA local INFILE '"!new!"' IGNORE into table db.table  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"'  (prodID,@timeStamp,Ch1,Ch2,Ch3,Ch4,Ch5,Ch6,Ch7,Ch8) SET timeStamp=STR_TO_DATE(@timeStamp,'%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s.%%f')" -u user -ppass
  echo %%~nxf DONE
)


12499,"2014-01-28 11:00:00.0",0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0
12499,"2014-01-28 12:00:00.0",0,4,0,0,1,0,0,2
12499,"2014-01-28 13:00:00.0",0,1,0,0,4,0,0,4
12499,"2014-01-28 14:00:00.0",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7
12499,"2014-01-28 15:00:00.0",0,0,0,0,3,0,0,2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the MySQL import process requires the "%" character be used in date/time formatting. Unfortunately, that character is also claimed by the Windows batch process.
The real question is "how to escape the percent characters in the SQL statement such that they are ignored by the for loop in the batch file, i.e. get sent through to MySQL unchanged?"
The answer that seemed to work for me was to use %%^ in the SQL statement, thus:

```
echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN ("*.csv") DO (
set old=%%~dpnxf
set new=!old:\=\\!
mysql -e "LOAD DATA local INFILE '"!new!"' IGNORE into table db.table  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"'  (prodID,@timeStamp,Ch1,Ch2,Ch3,Ch4,Ch5,Ch6,Ch7,Ch8) SET timeStamp=STR_TO_DATE(@timeStamp,'%%^Y-%%^m-%%^d %%^H:%%^i:%%^s.%%^f')" -u user -ppass
  echo %%~nxf DONE
)
```

Comment: Further to my previous, I think the answer is to use %%^ in the SQL statement, thus:
...SET timeStamp=STR_TO_DATE(@timeStamp,'%%^Y-%%^m-%%^d %%^H:%%^i:%%^s.%%^f')...

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

pushd "D:\bat\SO\files"
FOR %%f IN ("*.csv") DO (
  if /I "%%~nxf"=="31212125.csv" (
    set "old=%%~dpnxf"
    set "new=!old:\=\\!"
    echo old="!old!" new="!new!"
    echo(
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=," %%G IN ("!old!") DO (
      rem mysql -e "LOAD DATA local INFILE '"!new!"' IGNORE into table db.table  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"'  (prodID,@timeStamp,Ch1,Ch2,Ch3,Ch4,Ch5,Ch6,Ch7,Ch8) SET timeStamp=STR_TO_DATE(@timeStamp,'%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s.%%f')" -u user -ppass
      echo G=%%~G [H]=[%%~H] I=%%~I 
    )
  ) else rem echo skipped %%~nxf
)
popd
```

The above script shows the way how input file lines could be parsed. Operational `mysql` command is commented up *unchanged* as imho the question is about `.bat` scripting rather than `mysql`. Note that `if /I "%%~nxf"=="31212125.csv"` is here merely to skip *my other test CSVs*.

**Output**:

```
==>type D:\bat\SO\files\31212125.csv
12499,"2014-01-28 11:00:00.0",0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0
12500,"2014-01-28 12:00:00.0",0,4,0,0,1,0,0,2
12501,"2014-01-28 13:00:00.0",0,1,0,0,4,0,0,4
12502,"2014-01-28 14:00:00.0",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7
12503,"2014-01-28 15:00:00.0",0,0,0,0,3,0,0,2

==>D:\bat\SO\31212125.bat
old="D:\bat\SO\files\31212125.csv" new="D:\\bat\\SO\\files\\31212125.csv"

G=12499 [H]=[2014-01-28 11:00:00.0] I=0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0
G=12500 [H]=[2014-01-28 12:00:00.0] I=0,4,0,0,1,0,0,2
G=12501 [H]=[2014-01-28 13:00:00.0] I=0,1,0,0,4,0,0,4
G=12502 [H]=[2014-01-28 14:00:00.0] I=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7
G=12503 [H]=[2014-01-28 15:00:00.0] I=0,0,0,0,3,0,0,2

==>
```

Comment: I've monkeyed with that script you  put together over the weekend and a bit more today, and I can see that it outputs as you say, but won't import anything into the database.  I'll be honest though, I have no idea what's going on with the modifications you've made.  I will keep Googling and hopefully it will make more sense, but I do appreciate your work.  It would seem I have a lot to learn about .bat scripting.